# Windows Batch Files and "&"

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using the following batch file to created sorted .m3u playlists within my networked media folder:

```
@Echo Off
color 0e
Echo PLEASE WAIT, BUILDING PLAYLIST FILE, EXCLUDING BAT, TXT, M3U, SRT and JPG FILES
del "playlist.m3u"
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _t0=1
If ["%CD%"]==["%CD:~0,3%"] Set _t0=0
For /F "tokens=*" %%A In ('Dir "%*" /a-d /b /on /s ^|findstr /v /i ".bat .m3u .txt .db .srt .jpg"^| sort') Do (
Set _t1=%%A
Set _t2=!_t1:%CD%=!
Echo !_t2:~%_t0%!)>>playlist.m3u
```

Sample folder structure:

```
E:\Share\Media\TV\SHOW_NAME\Season 1\
E:\Share\Media\TV\SHOW_NAME\Season 2\
```

...etc

Sample script output (playlist.m3u):

```
SHOW_NAME\Season 1\S01E01.avi
SHOW_NAME\Season 1\S01E02.avi
SHOW_NAME\Season 1\S01E03.avi
SHOW_NAME\Season 2\S02E01.avi
```

...etc

You will notice that the .m3u is lacking the full path (this is intentional) as I want the script to be flexible. Users can map the drive at any depth/drive letter, or access the share as UNC (`domain.com\Share\Media\TV\SHOW_NAME`)... etc and the .m3u playlists still function. The trouble I am having lately is that if a folder contains the ampersand (&) symbol, the script does not function as intended. I created a sample folder:

```
E:\Share\Media\NEW&FOLDER\Season 1
```

Sample .m3u playlist:

```
t1:E:\Share\Media\NEW
t1:E:\Share\Media\NEW
t1:E:\Share\Media\NEW
t1:E:\Share\Media\NEW
t1:E:\Share\Media\NEW
```

The PROMPT reports the following:

```
 Set _t2=!_t1:E:\Share\Media\NEW  & FOLDER=!
 Echo !_t2:~1!
) 1>>playlist.m3u
'FOLDER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong? I had much help from this forum in creating this batch file - any insights would be appreciated.

P.S. have tested this on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012R2.

Answer (score 1):

Always use `set "variable=value"` to avoid such problems in your batch code. In your batch code you need to use for example `Set "_t2=!_t1:%CD%=!"`

`&` has a special meaning, except in double quoted strings.

Run `cmd /?` in a command prompt window and read at least last help page output by this command to really filter out files with the specified file extensions.

Here is your macro with additionally updating also parameters of command `findstr`. `/L` is needed to interpret `.` as dot and not as regular expression character for matching any character except newline character. Option `/E` is required to get a positive match for the file extension only at end of a file name.

```
@echo on
color 0e
echo PLEASE WAIT, BUILDING PLAYLIST FILE, EXCLUDING BAT, TXT, M3U, SRT and JPG FILES
if exist "playlist.m3u" del "playlist.m3u"
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_t0=1"
if "%CD%"=="%CD:~0,3%" set "_t0=0"
for /F "tokens=*" %%A In ('dir %* /a-d /b /on /s ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /I /E /L ".bat .m3u .txt .db .srt .jpg" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe') do (
    set "_t1=%%A"
    set "_t2=!_t1:%CD%=!"
    echo !_t2:~%_t0%!>>playlist.m3u
)
endlocal
```

Comment: +1, Generally good advice, but not 100% accurate. It all depends on the order that the batch parser works. Normal expansion happens before poison characters are detected, so quotes are not needed when using normal expansion. This works: `set var=%var:a&b=%`. But this doesn't: `set var=!var:a&b=!`. It's probably a good practice to use quotes in both cases, even though they are only needed in the second.

Comment: @Mofi @dbenhamFANTASTIC!

Comment: @Mofi Thank you so much!

I have a newly discovered issue now: the script will not run for any folder containing the word "bat. For example:

Could Not Find E:\Share\Media\TV\Batman
Could not find E:\Share\Media\TV\Battlestar Galactica

Any thoughts? Test folder "Idontwannabeabatmanguy" doesn't work either.

Comment: See the updated batch code in my edited answer above.